# SQL how to find if a certain bit is on

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit, flags, bitmask

```
Select '5th bit on'
Where 16 & (2^(5-1)) > 0
```

Why doesn't this work?
I just want to find out if a certain bit from decimal to binary is on/off.
I'm must be missing something very elementary.

Comment: I don't know if `> 0` is a good choice here. You might hit the sign bit an all of a sudden have a negative yet non zero number. Maybe `<> 0` is the safer bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` is the [xor operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR), not the "power of" operator I suspect you expect it to be. Instead, you can use the [`power`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
Select '5th bit on'
Where 16 & (POWER(2, (5-1))) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you Mureinik!